# CSS Selector for No-Children-But-Not-Empty

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to select BONKERS in the HTML fragment below.  Its distinction is that it's alone in a `<code>` block whereas all its siblings contain `<a>`'s. `:empty` is the obvious choice, but won't work due to the text node. I thought I knew this stuff but this is driving me, well, bonkers.

```
 <ul class="Reference">
    <li class="level4">
        <code class="active-voice">
            <a href="some/url/x" version="2">
                mauve 
            </a>
    </code>
    <li class="level8">
        <code class="active-voice">
            BONKERS 
        </code>
    </li>
    <li class="level9 subclass">
        <code class="active-voice">
            <a href="some/url/c" version="2">
                cerise 
            </a>
    </code>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need a pure CSS solution (JS isn't an option), and have no control over the source HTML.

Feh!

Comment: I can't think of any selector that will achieve this currently. Next level of selectors has an option.

Comment: What are you trying to style here? Are you selecting an `a` or `code`?

Comment: @choz I'm trying to style "BONKERS," and only it.

Comment: I suspect @Harry is right, and that this simply isn't possible.

Comment: There's no way to select it by its content. CSS had pseudo `:contains()` but they removed it in CSS3. You should use different approach to select that element, otherwise use jQuery. Ever considered doing `<code data-text='bonker'> BONKER </code>`?

Comment: :contains() wouldn't solve the problem anyway. :contains() matches elements by their text content, not by what sort of child elements they have (or don't have).

Comment: If you know at what position it occurs you can use [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) or [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) ... Not the answer you want to hear and also not the one I was looking for when I came here, but maybe useful for someone, somewhere...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can follow this approach. Style the `code` elements by whatever CSS you want and then reset those CSS styles which are inheritable in `anchor`'s styles i.e.:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1062/

**CSS:**

```
code {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
code a{
    color: red;/*Reset any inheritable css*/
    font-weight: normal; /*Reset any inheritable css*/
}
```

You might not need to reset all styles because not all styles are inherited by `anchor` from the `code` element

This is one solution which you can really consider.

Comment: This solution won't work when we need to hide the element based on whether it has a child element or not.

Answer (score 21):

Depending on what CSS properties you intend to apply, you may or may not be able to do this. If you're going to apply something like `color` for example, you can simply set it to all `code` elements and reset it in `code a`, assuming all the text is contained within that `a` and not spilled outside of it within the `code`. This will only work for a handful of properties, however (mostly the font ones).

Otherwise, there's not much in the way of pure CSS here, if you're trying to select `code` elements that don't contain `a` children. jQuery has `code:not(:has(> a))` (or, for any arbitrary `E` element with no child elements at all, `E:not(:has(> *))`), but [that's not coming to CSS anytime soon](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#profiles), and Selectors 4 doesn't provide anything else for "an element with no child elements".

"Feh!" is right.

Comment: @S16: Has it now? The ED hasn't been updated since August, and I can't find anything that suggests the CSSWG agreed to promote :has() to the live profile.

Comment: Hmm. I'm using it in firefox and chrome at the moment.

Comment: @S16: That's odd. Are you sure this isn't with the aid of a JS selector library? Neither browser has shipped it natively AFAIK.

Comment: You may be correct. I'm using a plugin in FF/Chrome and they must be using Sizzle or something similar to do their css selectors instead of native css.

Answer (score 1):

Use [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) in :not

```
code:not(:has(a))
```

Comment: :has is not support in half of the browsers so its better to avoid using that

Answer (score 0):

It's fine now, as long as you don't have to support IE,and I hope that you don't. :has it up