# How to select all fundamental elements using css?

Tags: html, css

If I have HTML like below:

```
<div id="root">
    <div>ABC</div>
    <div>
        333
        <div>hihihi</div>
        <ul>
            <li>A1</li>
            <li>A2</li>
            <li>A3</li>
        </ul>
        ABN
    </div>
    kkk
    <span>HHHIII</span>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google!</a>
</div>
```

How can I select all fundamental elements using css? That is, I want to select the elements which have no their child(s) anymore. In the example above, I want to select the elements, which innerText are ABC, hihihi, A1, A2, A3, HHHIII, Google!.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but it sounds like you're trying to select any element that doesn't have children - is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're going to have a lot of success with CSS. It really doesn't have the capability you're asking for, at least not in the very broad way you want to use it. If you were limited to a handful of elements you could implement the options listed as the [**Duplicate Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077658/css-selector-for-no-children-but-not-empty).

With that I present a JS solution. YMMV depending on how large your DOM is.

```js
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll( '*' );

nodeList.forEach( function ( el ) {
  if ( 0 === el.children.length ) {
    el.classList.add( 'highlight' );
  }
} );
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <div>ABC</div>
    <div>
        333
        <div>hihihi</div>
        <ul>
            <li>A1</li>
            <li>A2</li>
            <li>A3</li>
        </ul>
        ABN
    </div>
    kkk
    <span>HHHIII</span>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google!</a>
</div>
```